# Visable download to disc starts after download to browser finishes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, file, express

I'm currently trying to download files from my mongo DB.
Once I start the download I can see that in the network tab of chrome dev tools the file is downloading. Once it finishes here it's downloaded to the local drive. I really don't know how to skip this and download directly to the local drive.

This is quit bad for the user experience due to the fact, that the files are quite big and it seems like nothing happens.

Server Side:

```
app.get('/download/single',function(req,res){
        gfs.findOne({ _id: req.query.targetFile}, function(err,file){
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send(err);
            }
            else if (!file) {
                return res.status(404).send('Error on the database looking for the file.');
            }
            else{
                res.set('Content-Type', "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
                var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
                    _id: req.query.targetFile,
                })
                readstream.pipe(res)
                readstream.on('end',function(){
                    res.end()
                })
            }
        })

})
```

Client Side:

```
app.service('Download',function($http){
    this.single = function(id){
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/download/single',
            params: {
                targetFile: id
            },
            transformResponse: [function (data) {
                return data;
            }]
        }).success(function(response){
            return response
        })
    }

})
app.controller('downloadCtrl',function($scope,$routeParams,$window,Download){
        Download.single($routeParams.id).success(function(data){
            if(data){
                var blob = new Blob([data], {
                    type: "application/vnd.android.package-archive"
                })
                saveAs(blob,'test.apk',true)
            }
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

my recommendation is to put the chunk of code to inside some function that is callend on the event of your choice

```
$scope.showLoader = false;
$scope.onSomeButtonClick = function() {
  $scope.showLoader = true;
  Download.single($routeParams.id).success(function(data){
    $scope.showloader = false;
    if(data){
      var blob = new Blob([data], {
        type: "application/vnd.android.package-archive"
      })
      saveAs(blob,'test.apk',true)
    }
  })
}
```

what is happening in your case, the controller gets initialized, and starts executing its code. what you want to do initialize only the event listeners, that you wish to start the download.

hope this helps. cheers

Comment: thanks mate! sadly it's not fixing my problem. now i just have the same problem on the button press ;) .

Comment: My appologies, what do you want to happen when you execute the Download.signle call? (if not downloading to the drive)

Comment: Do you want to show some sort of loader or something? Please reffer to the updated code. The idea is to show some sort of a loader inside the View where the controller is binded, to show the user that therer is some waiting.

Comment: also i want to tell you the that success function is deprecated, and you should stop using it, if you wish to upgrade your angular framework. use the .then() function

Comment: Ah allright, good to know. Actually I want to use the native loader of the browser itself. If this isn't possible I would implement my own loader.